# Startup always crashing and very slow

Tags: performance

I just updated to Blender 4.02 and am having crazy lag and crashes. Was hoping the update would fix the issue..
I'm using a Nvidea 4080 and 32gb RAM but for some reason I'm experiencing a lot of lag. when I start the file it takes about 20 - 40 seconds of not responding. I've never had this issue before.

Any ideas?

Thank you!
[image]